# Django optimización de Querys

Tags: python, base-de-datos, django, python-2.7, django-models

Estoy haciendo una consulta en mis vistas de Django con diferentes palabras y me gustaría optimizarlo haciendo uso de una lista.

Tengo este modelo

```
class Personas(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='id', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    nombre = models.CharField(db_column='nombre', unique=True, max_length=100)  # Field name made lowercase.


class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'personas'
```

Hasta ahora estoy haciendo

```
#siendo 'nombres' mi lista de argumentos a buscar
primerNombre = nombres.pop(0) #obtengo el primer argumento a buscar
answer = Personas.objects.filter(nombre__icontains = primerNombre)
for nombre in nombres:
    answer = answer | Personas.objects.filter(nombre__icontains = nombre) #Hago una union por cada consulta
```

Me vi obligado a hacer esto porque intenté

```
answer = answer | Personas.objects.filter(nombre__in = nombres)
```

Y no me funcionó, al parecer el "__in" solo funciona con números. Hay alguna forma mas elegante u optima de hacerlo? Desde ya muchísimas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es que `__in` sólo se pueda usar con números, el asunto es que la lista de nombres que estás usando no es igual al nombre que tienes registrado en la BD, lo que no se puede hacer es combinar `__icontains` con `__in`, pero si te aseguras de que los nombres en la lista `nombres` esten escritos igual que en la BD, tal vez pre procesandolo con `.title()`, `.lower()` o `.upper()`; vas a poder usar `__in` en tu consulta:

```
Personas.objects.filter(nombre__in = nombres)
```

Comment: Gracias por responder! Al final encontré una solución con el método reduce() que me vino genial:
 `videos = Personas.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(nombre__icontains=x) for x in palabras)))` 
Saludos!

Comment: agrega tu respusta @Genarito es muy diferente a la de Gocht

Comment: Listo! Ahí agregué la respuesta

Answer (score 2):

Encontré otra forma de realizar la consulta gracias al operador `reduce`:

```
videos = Personas.objects.filter(reduce(operator.or_, (Q(nombre__icontains=x) for x in palabras)))
```

Espero que a alguien le sirva